# ziping all files in a folder without all directories

Tags: linux, command, zip, archive

I used
 this command to zip all files in a folder :
`zip -r fixedrom.zip /sdcard/dbtools/zipfix/fix/ ;`

It works fine but the zip should be like this :
Meta-inf 
Recovery
System
Boot.IMG
Etc...

But after unziping  its like this
Sdcard>dbtools>zipfix>fix>(and files and folders above )
How to fix this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

zip does indeed keep the entire tree of directories you ask it to backup. Next time, I do recommend you to cd first to the directory that you want to be your root backup; in your case this would be:

```
cd /sdcard/dbtools/zipfix/fix/ 
zip -rp fixedrom.zip *
```

Now what you can do is after unzipping move the tree/files to the right directory, as in:

```
cd sdcard/dbtools/zipfix/fix/
mv * ../../../..
rm -rf sdcard
```